# Does bpms choosing depends on my programming language how about workflow engines?

Tags: android, workflow, business-process-management

if the answer is yes please introduce an android bpms or workflow engine.
my app is for online mobile buying and i want work with bpms, it is a university project.
**BMPS Tools & Workflow Engines :**

jBPM

Bonita

Intalio

ProcessMaker

Activiti

Oracle

Camunda

IBM BPM

Oracle BPMS

Microsoft BizTalk, Wf

SAP NetWeaver BPM

Software AG webMethods

Pagaystems PegaRULES

Appian BPMS

BizAgi BPM Suite

Bosch inubit Suite

OpenTex tBPM

Perceptive BPMONe

Progress Savvion

TIBCO ActiveMatrix BPM

Bonita Open Solution

Camunda Fox

Intalio|BPM

JBoss jBPM

Shark

YAWL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BPM engines are not based on mobile OS such as Android because they require scalability in terms of performance, security, volume of processing, collaboration...

In real life scenarios, they are residing on a dedicated server and accessed by clients which can include any kind of personal devices such as computers, tablets or smart phones.

In any case, the actual execution of the business processes is always on a back end server, the client are used as front end for displaying user interfaces (task listings, form for tasks...).

All BPMS propose an out of the box web application to render their user interfaces on client desktops. Some also provide mobile web applications but this is generally an extra option to be purchased.

For instance Bonita BPM provides a desktop web portal in its open source community edition and a mobile portal it it subscription edition.

Also, I would add that modern BPMS all implement the BPMN 2.0 standard for modeling business processes.

Hope this helps,